# Operator/= in Ratio Class is working in a wrong way

Tags: c++

Look at this code please:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Ratio
{
    public:
        Ratio(int a=0, int b=1) : num(a), den(b) {}
        Ratio& operator/=(const Ratio&);
        void print() {cout << num << "/" << den << endl;}
    private:
        int num, den;
};


Ratio& Ratio::operator/=(const Ratio& r)
{
    num*=r.den;
    den*=r.num;
    return *this;
}

int main()
{
    Ratio x(1,2), y(2,5);
    y/=x;
    y.print();
}
```

after executing this code, (y) should be 5/4, I have calculate it several times by my hands! But in output after printing (y), it shows 4/5! It is inverted by it should not be!

Where is the problem with my code? really I have checked it several and several times and it seems it does not have any problem! It is a homework :)

Comment: I think this does exactly what you have written, maybe not what you intended.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How did you decide it should be 5/4? (2/5) / (1/2) = 4/5 and it is correct result. Maybe you are calculating x/=y instead when you expect 5/4.

Answer (score 2):

`y/=x` is same as `y = y/x` which is `2/5 / 1/2` which is `2/5 x 2/1` = `4/5`

Comment: yes, I know what is /= ;), I was calculating it in a wrong way :))